# official PerformanceCounters and their usage with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, performancecounter

I'm tasked to use the ado.net performance counters (in C#)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters -
  I get them working for sql but after many hours of googeling I still don't know how to use them for Oracle. I think it will be an really easy switch but I don't find anything.
  Could you please help me?
  *Link corrected

Comment: what about googling?

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET 2.0 introduced expanded support for performance counters that includes support for both `System.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Data.OracleClient`.

The System.Data.SqlClient performance counters available in previous versions of ADO.NET have been deprecated and replaced with the new performance counters discussed in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters

Comment: my bad, I posted the wrong link. This is the correct link, but this also shows only SQL and no Oracle...

Comment: did you check Oracle docs also? e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167/featConnecting.htm#CJADIIFD

Comment: no, I didn't get them via google. Seems promising. Thanks a lot!